# Android Asynctask run one by one in order

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a lot of asynctask, and run one by on in order. 
Is it possible? I can't find any solution for this.

onPostExecute and then call a new AsnycTask again is not a good solution for me.

SO what I want:

```
async1.execute
async2.execute
async3.execute

async1.over->async2.start
async2.over->async3.start
```

Comment: [**Specially for you**](http://nobalg.tumblr.com/post/98543748225/android-asynctasks-one-after-the-other)

Comment: `onPostExecute and then call a new AsnycTask again is not a good solution for me.` Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the serial executor (default in API 11 and above), this happens automatically. If you need this to work before API 11, you need to do the classic wait/notify trick (https://www.science.uva.nl/ict/ossdocs/java/tutorial/java/threads/waitAndNotify.html)

Answer (score 1):

Do like

```
async1.execute

then write async2.execute into onPostexecute of async1

and then write async3.execute into onPostexecute of async2
```

*There is no any other valid way. You can think about to implement threads (wait/notify), but that is not for asyntask.*

Comment: "onPostExecute and then call a new AsnycTask again is not a good solution for me."

Comment: @user2717954 why not?

Comment: hell if I know that what OP wrote

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should use Executor whit BlockQueue instead of AsyncTask, and use Handler to send handle the result. BockQueue is a FIFO data structure, and fit your flavor...

Answer (score 0):

Let the first AsyncTask is `MyAsyncTask1` and the second one is `MyAsyncTask2`. Now what you want is.

Execute the `MyAsyncTask1` from with in the activity
Take the response received
Now on successfull response,execute the `MyAsyncTask2`
what about calling them in sequence like:

```
MyAsyncTask1.execute();

MyAsyncTask2.execute();
```

The problem with the above code can be understood by the fact that calling execute on the `AsyncTask` object will create a  new thread to run in different memory space,and immediately the next `AyncTask` will be started with in its own memory space.But that was not what we want.We want that the first thread must finish its working and only then the second one will start to work.How this can be achieved?

The answer lies in the `onPostExecute()`.This is the method which will help you to get rid of this situation.While you call execute on `MyAsyncTask1` then after `doInBackground()` of the first `AsyncTask` its,`onPostExecute()` will be called .Place a check in that `onPostExecute()` that if response is null, if received response is not equal to null,and is a valid response then call execute on the `MyAsyncTask2`(with respective parameters if specified).

[**SEE THIS**](http://nobalg.tumblr.com/post/98543748225/android-asynctasks-one-after-the-other)

You can do this in a chain.....

Answer (score 0):

```
        // Async Task Class here async1
        class YourAsynClass extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Shows Progress Bar Dialog and then call doInBackground method
                showDialog(progress_bar_type);
            }


            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... PassYourdata) {

             // do your stuff here 
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String IFYouwantPassData) {
                // Dismiss the dialog 
                dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);
                // here async2
                new SecondAsyncTask.execute(Passeddata);
            }
        }
```

and in the third one do the same